# Can I set longer time interval for Windows camera time-lapse photo capture?

Tags: windows-10, camera

The default time lapse for `Windows` `camera` is 2, 5, 10 seconds. Can I set it longer without a third-party software?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows camera time lapse cannot be customized and is hard-wired
into the program.

You need third-party software for doing this.
Here are a couple that might do the job:

- [Chronolapse](https://www.chronolapse.com/) :
  Free and open-source
- [Panolapse](http://www.panolapse360.com/) :
  The free version is limited to 1280x720 output and 60 frames.

Comment: The Windows camera already detects the webcam. But when "Webcam - Configure" is clicked on the ChronoLapse, it says "No webcam found on your system".